# Run commands as another passwordless user - sudo fails?

Tags: permissions, sudo, users

I log on to my server as `userA`, this user has a `bash` shell, everything works fine with it.

Then, for the purposes of a program, I've had to do `sudo adduser --system --home=/home/userB --group userB`; this user is apparently passwordless, judging by the contents of `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`:

```
$ grep userB /etc/passwd
userB:x:Z08:WW9::/home/userB:/bin/false
$ sudo grep userB /etc/shadow
userB:*:16XXX:0:YYYYY:7:::
```

Also, there is no `/home/userB/.profile`, nor any `/home/userB/.bash*` files in the `userB` home directory.

Now, while I'm logged in as `userA`, I'd like to run commands as `userB`, in particular inspect the `$PATH` that `userB` sees. So I've tried to edit via `EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano sudo visudo`, and add either of the `userA` lines:

```
...
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
#userA      ALL=(userB) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash
userA       ALL = (userB) NOPASSWD: ALL
...
```

... then save the file, logout from remote shell, re-login back as `userA`. Then I try running:

```
$ sudo -iu userB; echo $?
1
$ sudo -S -u userB -i /bin/bash -l -c 'echo $HOME'; echo $?
1
$ sudo -i -u userB echo \$HOME; echo $?
1
```

... and clearly, nothing works - and there is no error either. Then I thought I'd `strace` one of these commands, and indeed I got an error:

```
$ strace sudo -iu userB
...
write(2, "sudo: effective uid is not 0, is"..., 140sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
) = 140
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

However, `nosuid` is not a problem on this root partition, I guess:

```
$ mount | grep '/ '
/dev/sdaX on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
```

So now I really have no idea what to do. Is it possible at all to have `userA` in this case run commands (e.g. print the `$HOME` environment variable) as `userB` - and if so, how can I get it to work?

Comment: A `*` in the password field in `/etc/shadow` means "no login", rather than "no password".

Comment: You can't `strace` setuid programs; the setuid flag is ignored if you try.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that @SatoKatsura - that is indeed a very important distinction, had no idea of that until now. I know `!` in `/etc/shadow` (instead of `*`) should mean "locked", so that would not help - Any ideas how I could have a quick hack around that?

Comment: Thanks @StephenHarris - I wasn't aware of that, good to realize that is what the error message is about. Any way to get a more verbose error message out of `sudo` in this case?

Comment: Set a password with `passwd userB`.

Comment: What happens if you change userB's shell to `/bin/bash`?  Currently it is set to `/bin/false`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura userB does not need a password because no userB credentials are ever being asked for.  `*` is good, here.

Comment: Many thanks @SatoKatsura - how would I restore the current state after I use `passwd userB`? Is replacing the `/etc/shadow` line with what is currently there acceptable? Feel free to post this as an answer, BTW, I'll accept it...

Comment: Many thanks @StephenHarris - it was set to `/bin/bash` in the previous line, apparently (the one now commented in my snippet)? I've tested that one out, but still I get the same error (i.e. `sudo` exits with `1`)...

Comment: No, not in sudoers, in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: Many thanks, @StephenHarris - didn't notice the `/bin/false` in `/etc/passwd` for `userB` until you commented - replaced it with `/bin/bash` and that was it; now the `sudo` commands work! Feel free to post this as an answer, I'll accept it... Also now both `sudoers` lines seem to work - and actually it seems to work without them as well ?! Still, great that it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `sudo` manpage:

```
-i, --login
             Run the shell specified by the target user's password data-
             base entry as a login shell.
```

Your userB has `/bin/false` as the shell, so that's the command that is run.

```
% /bin/false ; echo $? 
1
```

So to fix this you need to change the shell of userB to `/bin/bash` (or `/bin/sh` or whatever you prefer) *or* don't use the `-i` flag to sudo.   Do you need a login shell?

Comment: Many thanks @StephenHarris - that explains it; cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The `-i` option in sudo attempts to create a login shell, which in turn launches the user's chosen shell. You have set this to `/bin/false` in your `/etc/passwd`:

```
$ grep userB /etc/passwd
userB:x:Z08:WW9::/home/userB:/bin/false
```

Try running:

```
sudo -u userB ls
```

If this works then it is all working as you have configured it to. If you want a interactive shell use `-s` instead which will not call the user's login shell.

If you want a full login shell you must change the user's shell with

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash userB
```

Comment: Many thanks @MichaelDaffin - indeed,  `sudo -u userB ls` even with `/bin/false` in `/etc/passwd`; great to know this!